# Harmonicity of the Solution of the Dirichlet Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

The solution of the Dirichlet problem
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
 \Delta u=&0, ~~~ in~~\Omega\\
 u=&f, ~~~ on ~~\partial\Omega
 \end{split}
 \end{equation*}
interms of Green's function, $ G(\textbf{r'}, \textbf{r}) $, is given by
\begin{equation}
 u(\textbf{r})=-\int_{\partial\Omega}f(\textbf{r'})\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}G(\textbf{r'}, \textbf{r})d\sigma, ~~~ \textbf{r}\in\Omega.
 \end{equation}
Where $ \Omega $ is a domain in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $.

The question is show that $ u $, in the above equation, is harmonic in $ \Omega $. i.e $ \Delta u=0 $.

I proceed like this:
From Green's first identity for $ u $ and $ G $
$$\int_{\partial\Omega}u\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial n}d\sigma=\int_{\Omega}u\Delta G+(\nabla u).(\nabla G)dv$$
But as $ G $ is harmonic, $ \Delta G $ vanishes and as $ u=f $ on $ \partial\Omega $, the integral becomes
$$\int_{\partial\Omega}f\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial n}d\sigma=\int_{\Omega}(\nabla u).(\nabla G)dv$$

Hence $$u(\textbf{r})=-\int_{\Omega}(\nabla u).(\nabla G)dv$$ And I need to show $$\nabla^2 u(\textbf{r})=\nabla^2 \int_{\Omega}(\nabla u).(\nabla G)dv=0$$
But how could I do this? Any help?
Advance thanks.

Comment: Your Green's function formula for $u$ seems wrong, I think it should be $$u(\boldsymbol x)=\int_{\Omega }G(\boldsymbol x',\boldsymbol x)f(\boldsymbol x')\mathrm d^n\boldsymbol x' $$

Comment: My mistake, wrong Green's function. It is a bit confusing. This is usually referred to as the Poisson Kernel.

Comment: Actually yes. Since  $$\dfrac{\partial G(\textbf{r'},\textbf{r})}{\partial n}=P(\textbf{r'},\textbf{r}) ~~~\text{the Poisson kernel.}$$ The solution becomes $$u(\textbf{r})=-\int_{\partial\Omega}f(\textbf{r'})P(\textbf{r'},\textbf{r})d\sigma$$

Comment: But if the Laplacian operator pass through the integral, why does it only applied for $G$ what for $f$?

Comment: Berban its because the laplacian is with respect to the unprimed variable.

Comment: Yes, thanks oll.